# OkHttpClient interceptors not getting set

Tags: java, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using an injected `OkHttpClient` object in my class. I am using method injection to set some interceptors on my client object like following:

```
@Inject
private OkHttpClient httpClient;

@Inject
void onPostInject() {
    httpClient
       .newBuilder()
       .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
       .addInterceptor(httpClientInterceptor);
}
```

Now if I put a breakpoint in `onPostInject` method and reach the last statement, I see the size of `interceptors` collection within the `httpClient` object is 0. My Integration test is also failing because of the same reason.

Comment: can you add a little code how you are creating and initialising `interceptor`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed injection from the `httpClient` field and use the build a bit different to get it worked:

```
private OkHttpClient httpClient;

@Inject
void onPostInject() {
    httpClient =
        new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
        .addInterceptor(httpClientInterceptor)
        .build();
}
```